# convert c char to swift

Tags: ios, c, swift, swift2

I am trying to conver the following code to swift:

```
static unsigned char rsa2048Asn1Header[] = {
    0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x22, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86,
    0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x82, 0x01, 0x0f, 0x00
};

static unsigned char rsa4096Asn1Header[] = {
    0x30, 0x82, 0x02, 0x22, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86,
    0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x82, 0x02, 0x0f, 0x00
};

static unsigned char ecDsaSecp256r1Asn1Header[] = {
    0x30, 0x59, 0x30, 0x13, 0x06, 0x07, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x02,
    0x01, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07, 0x03,
    0x42, 0x00
 };

static unsigned char *asn1HeaderBytes[3] = { rsa2048Asn1Header, rsa4096Asn1Header, ecDsaSecp256r1Asn1Header };
static unsigned int asn1HeaderSizes[3] = { sizeof(rsa2048Asn1Header), sizeof(rsa4096Asn1Header), sizeof(ecDsaSecp256r1Asn1Header) };
```

My swift code looks like this:

```
let rsa2048Asn1Header:[CUnsignedChar] = [0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x22, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d,0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x82, 0x01, 0x0f, 0x00]

let rsa4096Asn1Header:[CUnsignedChar] = [0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x22, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x82, 0x01, 0x0f, 0x00]

let ecDsaSecp256r1Asn1Header:[CUnsignedChar] = [0x30, 0x59, 0x30, 0x13, 0x06, 0x07, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x02, 0x01, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07, 0x03, 0x42, 0x00]


let asn1HeaderBytes:[[CUnsignedChar]] = [rsa2048Asn1Header, rsa4096Asn1Header, ecDsaSecp256r1Asn1Header]

let asn1HeaderSizes:[UInt] = [sizeof(rsa2048Asn1Header.dynamicType).toUInt, sizeof(rsa4096Asn1Header.dynamicType).toUInt, sizeof(ecDsaSecp256r1Asn1Header.dynamicType).toUInt]
```

However i failing at his badly, per example using rsa2048Asn1Header and converting it to NSData:

```
let data:NSData = NSData(bytes: rsa2048Asn1Header, length:strideofValue(rsa2048Asn1Header))
```

swift prints with length 8:

```
<30820122 300d0609>
```

objc for the following code:

```
[NSData dataWithBytes:rsa2048Asn1Header length:sizeof(rsa2048Asn1Header)];
```

prints

```
<30820122 300d0609 2a864886 f70d0101 01050003 82010f00> size: 24
```

looking at apple documentation, strideOfvalue should return the right size for each one of those [CUnsignedChar] but that doesnt seem to be the case, my question is shouldnt a [CUnsignedChar] have same size as usigned char [] in objc, if not what could i use to change?

also [[CUnsignedChar]] makes no sense whatsoever in my head, how would the code below convert to swift, should i convert those arrays to an NSString and extract the CString when required, if so what encoding should I use?

```
static unsigned char *asn1HeaderBytes[3] = { rsa2048Asn1Header, rsa4096Asn1Header, ecDsaSecp256r1Asn1Header };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `strideofValue` is the function you are looking for. I haven't heard of it before, but the documentation states:

> Returns the least possible interval between distinct instances of T in memory. The result is always positive.

If this is returning `8`, that means that the minimum distance between `[CUnsignedChar]`s in memory is 8 bytes.

To use `NSData(data:length:)` properly, the second parameter needs to be the size of the array. You can use the `count` property for this:

```
let data: NSData = NSData(bytes: rsa2048Asn1Header, length:rsa2048Asn1Header.count)
```

---

`[[CUnsignedChar]]` is an array of arrays (two-dimensional array) of `CUnsignedChar`.

Your headers are raw bytes, so technically no encoding is 'correct' to convert to `NSString`. The cryptographic headers you have don't appear to be strings, and contain unprintable characters.

Comment: With regards to count it makes complete sense, i will attempt to proceed with my implementation. I still dunno what will be the equivalent of asniheaderbytes pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use strideofValue function. 'strideofValue' it's not a replacement for 'sizeof'. Just go for ".count" property.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, i tried all sorts but for some reason never thought of using count:(